# what does java protected constructor mean

Tags: java

I want to know why a protected constructor class can be instantiated anywhere.
I know protected field only can be used in subclass.

Such as `org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference` in Jackson, constructor is protected, but it can be instantiated in any code.

```
public abstract class TypeReference<T>
    implements Comparable<TypeReference<T>> {
    final Type _type;

    protected TypeReference()
    {
        Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
        }
        /* 22-Dec-2008, tatu: Not sure if this case is safe -- I suspect
         *   it is possible to make it fail?
         *   But let's deal with specifc
         *   case when we know an actual use case, and thereby suitable
         *   work arounds for valid case(s) and/or error to throw
         *   on invalid one(s).
         */
        _type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Type getType() { return _type; }

    /**
     * The only reason we define this method (and require implementation
     * of <code>Comparable</code>) is to prevent constructing a
     * reference without type information.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TypeReference<T> o) {
        // just need an implementation, not a good one... hence:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A protected constructor can be called from the class or from subclasses. This is useful if you want to construct new objects "from within", i.e. from a static method or by loading them from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `TypeReference` because it is an `abstract class` no matter what the modifier on the constructor is.

Most likely the way you are using this is via an anonymous class which is a *sub-class* of this class e.g.

```
TypeReference<List<String>> type = new TypeReference<List<String>>() { };
assert type.getClass() != TypeReference.class; // types are NOT the same.
```

Comment: ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();                                 om.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List>() {});